# Maven Multiple platform dependent Packages

Tags: windows, linux, maven, wix, deb

I have written an application in Java that can be used on both Linux and Windows.  Currently by running `mvn package`, my maven build system will generate a .msi using WiX.

Is there a way of creating two package 'tasks' so I can say either `mvn package-windows or`mvn package-linux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to package both versions (Linux and Windows), you can bind your mvn package phase to an extra phase that would build another artifact.

```xml
...
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.group.extra</groupId>
   <artifactId>extra-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       [...]
       </configuration>
       <goals>
         <goal>package</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
...
```

It was probably what you have already done with maven-wix-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either use profile to do that or a better thing would be to have three project.
One for the core and then one for Linux and one for Windows that uses the core project.